# how to remove bad box type error :- Overfull \hbox (4.55623pt too wide) detected

Tags: errors

Overfull \hbox (4.55623pt too wide) detected

I want to remove this

code is here:

```
    \documentclass[10pt,xcolor=svgnames]{beamer}
%\documentclass{article}

%usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{geometry}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\colorlet{white}{white}
\mode<presentation>
% 

%
%\usetheme{Dresden}
%\usecolortheme{beaver}
%\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=darkred!80!white}
%
%\usetheme{Singapore}
% \usetheme{Boadilla}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\usepackage{BeamerColor}
%\usetheme[]{Szeged}
%\The new themes are Warsaw, Boadilla, AnnArbor,Rochester,Antibes,JuanLesPins,Berlin,rounded,crane
%\usetheme[]{Szeged}
%\usetheme{Pittsburgh}
%\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
%\usetheme[hoptionsi]{Berkeley}
%\usecolortheme[]{wolverine}
%\usetheme[]{Berkeley}
%\usetheme{dresden}
%\usefonttheme{structureitalicserif}
\usetheme{Antibes}
%\usecolortheme{crane}
%\usetheme[]{}
%\usecolortheme[named=OliveGreen]{structure}
%\usecolortheme[named=Brown]{structure}
%\usecolortheme[named=OliveGreen]{structure}
%\usecolortheme{wolverine}
%\usecolortheme{oily}
%\setbeamerfont{}{size={50cm}}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[default]
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[ams style]
\usepackage{ragged2e}\justifying
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{epsf}
%\usepackage{graphics}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{cor}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{Algorithm}[theorem]{Algorithm}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\newcommand{\Date}{3 october 2019}% change the date here
\newcommand{\companyName}{Company Name Here} % change company name here
\newcommand{\Speaker}{Speaker} %change speaker name with 'speaker'
\newcommand{\SpeakerTitle}{Speaker's Title} %change speaker title with "Speaker's Title"
\title[company name]
{\LARGE \textbf{company name}}

\subtitle{}

\author[ABCD]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.25,0.00}{ABCD}}

\institute[]
{\inst{}%
 ABC Uni

}
%
\date[]{ }
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\documentclass{beamer}
\useoutertheme{split}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]
\pagestyle{plain}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rfoot{\thepage}

\begin{document}

%\begin{frame}
%  \titlepage
%\end{frame} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% FRAME 2 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%\bgroup
\usebackgroundtemplate{
    \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{1.png}} 
    \begin{frame}
  \tikz[remember picture, overlay] \fill[green] (current page.south west) rectangle ++(\paperwidth,0.27cm); %Draw green line at the bottom of the page

    \vspace*{-0.5in} %adjust this if your logo is being cropped from top
    \begin{flushleft}
        {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{2.png}}
        \vspace{-0.8cm}
        \newgeometry{textwidth = 5cm} % change it if you change the width of the logo
        \begin{flushright}
        {\textcolor{white}{A tagline for the company spans}}\\
        {\textcolor{white}{two lines just under the logo.}} \\
    \end{flushright}
        \vspace{-0.7cm}
        \newgeometry{textwidth = 5cm} % change it if you change the width of the logo
        \begin{flushright}
        {\textcolor{white}{\Date}}
        \end{flushright}
    \end{flushleft}


    \restoregeometry
%\textcolor{white}{\text{A tagline for the company \\ 
%spans two lines just under the logo}} 
%\vfill
\begin{columns}%beamer
    \column{0.45\textwidth}
    % blank
    \column{0.45\textwidth}
    \begin{flushleft}
        \begin{tcolorbox}[standard jigsaw, opacityback = 0, top =2cm, left = 0 cm, colframe=white, width = 4.5cm]
            \textcolor{white}{\textbf{CLICK TO ADD TITLE}}
        \end{tcolorbox}
        \textcolor{white}{\Speaker, \SpeakerTitle}
    \end{flushleft}

\end{columns}
%\section{1}
%\textcolor{white}{click to add title}
    \end{frame}

%\egroup
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% FRAME 3 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame}
\tikz[remember picture, overlay] \fill[green] (current page.south west) rectangle ++(\paperwidth,0.27cm); %Draw green line at the bottom of the page

\section{Open Ball, Closed Ball, Sphere}\label{1114}
\begin{flushleft}
\vbox{
    \begin{minipage}[t][0.0025\textheight][t]{\textwidth}
        \tiny{\companyName $ |$ \Date}
    \end{minipage}\\

    \begin{minipage}[b][0.2\textheight][b]{0.95\textwidth}
        \begin{tcolorbox}[standard jigsaw, opacityback = 0, top =0.5cm, bottom = 0.5cm, left = 0 cm, colframe=black]
    \textbf{CLICK TO ADD TITLE} %Edit this if you just want to change the text, else if you want to remove complete box then delete the block of "tcolorbox" and start writting required text
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{minipage}\\

    \begin{minipage}[t][0.5\textheight][t]{0.95\textwidth}
        \begin{tcolorbox}[standard jigsaw, opacityback = 0, bottom =2in , left = 0 cm, colframe=black]
    \textbf{CLICK TO ADD TITLE} %Edit this if you just want to change the text, else if you want to remove complete box then delete the block of "tcolorbox" and start writting required text
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{picture}(25, 30)(-293, -215)
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{3.png}
    \end{picture}
}
\end{flushleft}

\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% FRAME 4 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\bgroup
\usebackgroundtemplate{%
    \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{1.png}} 
\begin{frame}
\tikz[remember picture, overlay] \fill[green] (current page.south west) rectangle ++(\paperwidth,0.27cm); %Draw green line at the bottom of the page
    \vspace*{-1in} %adjust this if your logo is being cropped from top
    \begin{flushleft}
        {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{2.png}}
            \vspace{-0.75cm}
        \newgeometry{textwidth = 5cm} % change it if you change the width of the logo
        \begin{flushright}
        {\textcolor{white}{A tagline for the company spans}}\\
        {\textcolor{white}{two lines just under the logo.}} \\
    \end{flushright}
        \vspace{-0.6cm}
        \newgeometry{textwidth = 5cm} % change it if you change the width of the logo
        \begin{flushright}
        {\textcolor{white}{\Date}}
        \end{flushright}
    \end{flushleft}
    \restoregeometry

%\textcolor{white}{\text{A tagline for the company \\ 
%spams two lines just under the logo}} 
%\vfill
\begin{columns}%beamer
    \column{0.45\textwidth}
    % blank
    \column{0.45\textwidth}
    \begin{flushleft}
        \vspace{0.9cm}
    \textcolor{white}{\textbf{QUESTIONS?}}\\
    \vspace{0.2cm}
    \textcolor{white}{\Speaker, \SpeakerTitle}
    \end{flushleft}

\end{columns}
%   \section{1}
\thispagestyle{empty}

    \end{frame}
%\egroup
\end{document}
```

Comment: it's not an error just a warning, and in a presentation it probably doesn't matter if something is 4pt too big. we can not run your code to see the issue as it includes file that are not available.

Comment: why have you got tex primitives like `\hbox` here? `\hbox{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{2.png}}` should never appear in a latex document

Comment: also having `\bgroup..\egroup` around the frames is very odd

Comment: i have removed \hbox and \bgroup. But still these warnings remain same

Comment: yes they were just comments. As I said originally it is just warning you that some content is too big but as we can not run the document or see the content and you have not shown the actual warning text it is impossible to say. I do note though that you have two columns `\column{0.6\textwidth}` which clearly can not fit as they add up to more than 1.

Answer (score 1):

The warning that you mention is due to

```
\column{0.6\textwidth}
% blank
\column{0.6\textwidth}
```

which is obviously too wide (1.2 text width)

```
\begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}
% blank
 \end{column}
\begin{column{0.6\textwidth}
 .....
 \end{column}
```

would fit (note column is intended to be an environment)

Comment: Thanku so much @David . It got removed by adjusting column to 0.45.

Comment: Please help to remove this bad box also from the above updated code. >>>    Overfull \vbox (17.18265pt too high) detected

Comment: @maria -- That's a different question, and to be able to help, it's necessary to know what is in that box and where it comes from, but that's not identified here.